# How to apply opacity and blend mode at a time to images

Tags: go, image-processing, opacity

I am using a Go package [bild](https://github.com/anthonynsimon/bild), to apply Opacity and different blend modes.

I had to apply opacity and any other blend mode at a time to a foreground and background image. My problem is as the opacity function already overlays the foreground into the background image as expected, I am unable to apply any other blend modes like multiply or overlay, etc. If I try to apply blend modes after applying opacity it shows different images than expected. So how can I try Opacity and apply different blend modes at a time?

My opacity function is:

```
package filter

import (

    "image"
    "github.com/anthonynsimon/bild/blend"
)

func ChangeOpacity(backgroundImage image.Image, foregroundImage image.Image, opacity float64) *image.RGBA {
    return blend.Opacity(backgroundImage, foregroundImage, opacity)
}
```

function from where I am appling different blending modes:

```
package blend

import (
    "image"

    imageBlend "github.com/anthonynsimon/bild/blend"
)

func GetBlendImage(backgroundImage image.Image, foregroundImage image.Image, blend_type string) (image.Image) {
    
    switch blend_type {

    case "multiply":
        return imageBlend.Multiply(backgroundImage, foregroundImage)
    case "screen":
        return imageBlend.Screen(backgroundImage, foregroundImage)
    case "overlay":
        return imageBlend.Overlay(backgroundImage, foregroundImage)
    case "darken":
        return imageBlend.Darken(backgroundImage, foregroundImage)
    case "lighten":
        return imageBlend.Lighten(backgroundImage, foregroundImage)
    case "color-dodge":
        return imageBlend.ColorDodge(backgroundImage, foregroundImage)
    case "color-burn":
        return imageBlend.ColorBurn(backgroundImage, foregroundImage)
    case "hard-light":
        // return imageBlend.HardLight(backgroundImage, foregroundImage)
    case "soft-light":
        return imageBlend.SoftLight(backgroundImage, foregroundImage)

    default:
        return imageBlend.Normal(backgroundImage, foregroundImage)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Some solutions that I tried:
I tried to appliy opacity of the foreground image with an empty image, then applied the blending modes. But its still not showing expected output.

Comment: Post the images and it might be possible to tell you what is happening.